# choosing the correct password on the $n-$th try

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm current working on the following probability problem:

> A new secretary has been given $n$ computer passwords, only one of which will permit access
> to a computer file. Because the secretary has no idea which password is correct, he chooses
> one of the passwords at random and tries it. If the password is incorrect, he discards it and
> randomly selects another password from among those remaining, proceeding in this manner
> until he finds the correct password.

and

> A security system has been set up so that if three incorrect passwords are tried before
> the correct one, the computer file is locked and access to it denied. If $n = 7$, what is the
> probability that the secretary will gain access to the file?

One can work this out rather easily via intuition.
$$
\begin{align}
    \text{P(Correct password on first try)}=&\ \frac{1}{n}\\
    \text{P(Correct password on second try)}=&\ \text{P(wrong first try)}\cdot\text{P(correct second try)}\\
    =&\ \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}\\
    =&\ \frac{1}{n}\\
    \text{P(Correct password on third try)}=&\ \text{P(wrong first try)}\cdot\text{P(wrong second try)}\cdot\text{P(correct third try)}\\
    =&\ \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n-2}\\
    =&\ \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore the probability of getting access is $3\cdot\frac{1}{7}=\frac{3}{7}$.

My question is how can I formulate this rigorously? Particularly the conditional probability of the $i$-th attempt? Here's my attempt, but I find it rather clunky.

Denote $E$ as the event where the secretary gains access, $A_n$ as the event where the previous $(n-1)$ passwords picked were incorrect, and the $n-$th password was correct, and $k$ as the maximum attempts allowed. Thus
$$E=\bigcup^k_{i=1}A_i$$
Since each $A_{i}$ and $A_j$ is pairwise mutually exclusive,
$$P(E)=\sum^k_{i=1}P(A_i)$$
by one of the Kolmogorov axioms. Furtheremore, defining $T_i$ as the event where the $i$-th password picked is wrong, then

$$A_i=T_1\cap T_2\cap \ldots \cap T_{i-1} \cap \overline{T_i}$$
and for each $T$,
$$P(T_i)= \frac{n-i}{n -i+1}$$
and
$$P(\overline{T_i})=\frac{1}{n-i+1}$$
since each incorrect password is tossed out after the attempt. Finally,

$$A_i=\left(\frac{1}{n-i+1}\right)\cdot\prod^i_{j=1}\frac{n-i}{n -i+1}=\frac{1}{n}$$
which implies that
$$P(E)=\sum^k_{i=1}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{k}{n}$$

*Relevant: [Probability of guessing correct password (out of n) on k-th try when trying them at random](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3020461/probability-of-guessing-correct-password-out-of-n-on-k-th-try-when-trying-them)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $n$ passwords, and that security lock-out after $k$ failures: $k \in \{1,2,3,\cdots, (n-1)\}.$

Assume sampling done without replacement.

Line up the $n$ passwords in a row, in the order that they will be tried, and label them $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_n$.  Access attempt succeeds if and only if the correct password in $\{P_1, \cdots, P_k\}.$

Thus, probability is $\frac{k}{n}.$